# Concurrency handling of Sql transactrion

Tags: sql, concurrency

Suppose, I am about to start a project using ASP.NET and SQL Server 2005. I have to design the concurrency requirement for this application. I am planning to add a TimeStamp column in each table. While updating the tables I will check that the TimeStamp column is same, as it was selected.

Will this approach be suffice? Or is there any shortcomings for this approach under any circumstances?

Please advice.

Thanks

Lijo

Comment: Might not be a good idea - take a look at this article http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1501

Comment: Thanks. It gives some light. One question - why do we say that it is better to use locking than timestamp under pessimistic conditions? Suppose user1 read it and went outside his office, other users has to wait for long time before getting error message, right? If we are using timestamp approach can't we get instantaneous reply?

What is the missing link here?

Comment: "pessimistic conditions" means locking - that's why not many people who know what they are doing use it

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. The article says "Pessimistic concurrency works under the assumption that there will be frequent user conflicts ". Why do we apply locking when there is a high chance of conflicts? When locking is applied wouldn't the other users has to wait long time before getting an error message?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all the way which you describe in your question is in my opinion ***the best way*** for ASP.NET application with MS SQL as a database. There is no locking in the database. It is perfect with **permanently disconnected clients** like web clients.

How one can read from some answers, there is a misunderstanding in the terminology. We all mean using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 or higher to hold the database. If you open in the MS SQL Server 2008 documentation the topic "rowversion (Transact-SQL)" you will find following:

> "**timestamp** is the synonym for the
>   **rowversion** data type and is subject to
>   the behavior of data type synonym." …
>   "The **timestamp** syntax is deprecated.
>   This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature."

So **timestamp** data type is the synonym for the **rowversion** data type for MS SQL. It holds 64-bit the counter which exists internally in every database and can be seen as **@@DBTS**. After a modification of one row in one table of the database, the counter will be incremented.

As I read your question I read "TimeStamp" as a column name of the type **rowversion** data. I personally prefer the name *RowUpdateTimeStamp*. In AzManDB (see Microsoft Authorization Manager with the Store as DB) I could see such name. Sometimes were used also *ChildUpdateTimeStamp* to trace hierarchical *RowUpdateTimeStamp* structures (with respect of triggers).

I implemented this approach in my last project and be very happy. Generally you do following:

1. Add *RowUpdateTimeStam*p column to every table of you database with the type **rowversion** (it will be seen in the Microsoft SQL Management Studio as **timestamp**, which is the same).
2. You should construct all you SQL SELECT Queries for sending results to the client so, that you send additional *RowVersion* value together with the main data. If you have a SELECT with JOINTs, you should send *RowVersion* of the maximum *RowUpdateTimeStamp* value from both tables like

```sql
SELECT s.Id AS Id
    ,s.Name AS SoftwareName
    ,m.Name AS ManufacturerName
    ,CASE WHEN s.RowUpdateTimeStamp > m.RowUpdateTimeStamp
          THEN s.RowUpdateTimeStamp 
          ELSE m.RowUpdateTimeStamp 
     END AS RowUpdateTimeStamp 
FROM dbo.Software AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Manufacturer AS m ON s.Manufacturer_Id=m.Id
```

Or make a data casting like following

```sql
SELECT s.Id AS Id
    ,s.Name AS SoftwareName
    ,m.Name AS ManufacturerName
    ,CASE WHEN s.RowUpdateTimeStamp > m.RowUpdateTimeStamp
          THEN CAST(s.RowUpdateTimeStamp AS bigint)
          ELSE CAST(m.RowUpdateTimeStamp AS bigint)
     END AS RowUpdateTimeStamp 
FROM dbo.Software AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Manufacturer AS m ON s.Manufacturer_Id=m.Id
```

to hold *RowUpdateTimeStamp* as **bigint**, which corresponds **ulong** data type of C#. If you makes OUTER JOINTs or JOINTs from many tables, the construct `MAX(RowUpdateTimeStamp)` from all tables will be seen a little more complex. Because MS SQL don't support function like MAX(a,b,c,d,e) the corresponding construct could looks like following:

```sql
(SELECT MAX(rv)
 FROM (SELECT table1.RowUpdateTimeStamp AS rv
      UNION ALL SELECT table2.RowUpdateTimeStamp
      UNION ALL SELECT table3.RowUpdateTimeStamp
      UNION ALL SELECT table4.RowUpdateTimeStamp
      UNION ALL SELECT table5.RowUpdateTimeStamp) AS maxrv) AS RowUpdateTimeStamp
```

3. All disconnected clients (web clients) receive and hold not only some rows of data, but *RowVersion* (type **ulong**) of the data row.
4. In one try to modify data from the disconnected client, you client should send the *RowVersion* corresponds to the original data to server. The `spSoftwareUpdate` stored procedure could look like

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spSoftwareUpdate
    @Id int,
    @SoftwareName varchar(100),
    @originalRowUpdateTimeStamp bigint, -- used for optimistic concurrency mechanism
    @NewRowUpdateTimeStamp bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    -- ExecuteNonQuery() returns -1, but it is not an error
    -- one should test @NewRowUpdateTimeStamp for DBNull
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE dbo.Software
    SET Name = @SoftwareName
    WHERE Id = @Id AND RowUpdateTimeStamp <= @originalRowUpdateTimeStamp

    SET @NewRowUpdateTimeStamp = (SELECT RowUpdateTimeStamp
                                  FROM dbo.Software
                                  WHERE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0) AND (Id = @Id));
END
```

Code of `dbo.spSoftwareDelete` stored procedure look like the same. If you don’t switch on `NOCOUNT`, you can produce **DBConcurrencyException** automatically generated in a lot on scenarios. Visual Studio gives you possibilities to use optimistic concurrency like "Use optimistic concurrency" checkbox in Advanced Options of the `TableAdapter` or `DataAdapter`.

If you look at `dbo.spSoftwareUpdate` stored procedure carful you will find, that I use `RowUpdateTimeStamp <= @originalRowUpdateTimeStamp` in WHERE instead of `RowUpdateTimeStamp = @originalRowUpdateTimeStamp`. I do so because, the value of `@originalRowUpdateTimeStamp` which has the client typically are constructed as a `MAX(RowUpdateTimeStamp)` from more as one tables. So it can be that `RowUpdateTimeStamp < @originalRowUpdateTimeStamp`. Either you should use strict equality **=** and reproduce here the same complex JOIN statement as you used in SELECT statement or use **<=** construct like me and stay exact the same safe as before.

By the way, one can construct very good value for *ETag* based on RowUpdateTimeStamp which can sent in HTTP header to the client together with data. With the *ETag* you can implement intelligent data caching on the client side.

I can’t write whole code here, but you can find a lot of examples in Internet. I want only repeat one more time that in my opinion usage optimistic concurrency based on **rowversion** is ***the best way for the most of ASP.NET scenarios***.

Comment: Thanks for the detail answer, however, the stored procedure code looks incorrect or incomplete.   WHERE Id=@Id AND RowUpdateTimeStamp  0) ?  I know it's been 3 years but I just stumble on to this.

Comment: @Mike: Thanks, it was an old "cut & paste error" with wrong modification of the code! I updated the code of the STORED PROCEDURE `dbo.spSoftwareUpdate`. I hope now the code is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server a recommended approach for type of situation is to create a column of type ['rowversion'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) and use that to check if any of the fields in that row have changed.

SQL Server guarantees that if any value in the row changes (or a new row is inserted) it's rowversion column will automatically updated to different value.  Letting the database handle this for you is much more reliable than trying to do it yourself.

In your update statements you simply need to add a where clause to check that the rowversion value is the same as it was when you first retrieved the row. If not, someone else has changed the row (ie: it's dirty)

Also, from that page:

> The timestamp syntax is deprecated.
>   This feature will be removed in a
>   future version of Microsoft SQL
>   Server. Avoid using this feature in
>   new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use
>   this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that concurrency should be handled in the database like this.  The database itself should be able manage isolation and transactional behavior, but the threading behavior ought to be done in code.

Comment: He didn't mention threading. The database must be able to handle concurrent accesses - whether these come from a single multi-threaded app or from multiple app instances, or both, is neither here nor there.

Comment: Then it's ACID and isolation he needs to concern himself with.

Answer (score 0):

rowversion suggestion is correct I would say but its disappointing to see that timestamp will be deprecated soon. Some of my OLD applications are using this for different reasons then checking concurrency.