# Database concurrency issue in .NET application

Tags: .net, sql-server, concurrency, dataadapter

If userA deleted OrderA while userB is modifying OrderA, then userB saves OrderA then there is no order in the database to be updated.  My problem is there is no error!  The SqlDataAdapter.Update succeeds and returns a "1" indicating a record was modified when this is not true.  Does anybody know how this is supposed to work, thanks.

Comment: You might want to check out this MSDN Article on Optimistic Concurrency: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa0416cz(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use, at the very least, optimistic locking.  See here:

[Optimistic Locking](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/10/05/2503.aspx)

Basically, this says that you check the values of all fields during the update.  So you say, for example assuming when you first read record 1, bar was equal to 0:

```
UPDATE FOO SET BAR=1 WHERE ID=1 AND BAR=0
```

The idea is, if the record changes, the update will fail.  This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

When not working stateless (like webservices work), you could try pessimistic locking; more info here (VB example though): https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1049842.html

Answer (score 1):

I also find **Optimistic Concurrency** as the best way.

One should only decide which database field use as a criteria of update fails. It's depend on your situation, but there are one universal way to implement this. I personally use MS SQL Server and so prefer inserting not nullable `rowversion` fields (alias `timestamp`) in all tables of database (one field per table). So every row in your table will have a "`rowversion`" which will be updated **automatically** is somebody update a field of the row. So you just should use this field as a criteria of update fails. See also my old answer [Concurrency handling of Sql transactrion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658443/concurrency-handling/2663654#2663654) for the close information.

**UPDATED**: Because you use `SqlDataAdapter` to access the database, this links can be also interesting for you:

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-1050108.html

and on the next one just search for `DataRowVersion`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww3k31w0(VS.71).aspx,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(VS.80).aspx,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971491.aspx,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163908.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation similar to yours.  It involved an `SqlDataAdapter`, an `SqlCommandBuilder` connected to it, and a `DataTable` object.  Changes I made consistently failed to save, but giving no error.  It turned out that one of the columns in the `DataTable` object was misnamed.  Once I corrected it, it started working perfectly.  I still have no idea why this didn't raise an error.