# jqGrid Row updating

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a question about Jqgrid row updating. We have a database table like below.

id :1   field1: john    field2:black

Imagine a user wants to update the first row which has a field named id=1. The user double clicks the row and opens the details of the row. As you see the first rows field1 is john and field2 is black.
What will happen if another user double clicks the same row after first user and updates the field2 as red for example? First user is still on the updating screen. On his screen the field2 is still black. After that first user only updates the field1 as jack and saves the row. The result will be field1: jack, field2 : black. Because first user wasn't aware of the change of field2. And the second user's field2 change has gone away..
How can I prevent data loss on this example?

I update all the fields when user double clicks and saves any change in the row..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe is the standard [concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control) problem. In case of web development one use typically [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) to solve the problem. As ASP.NET developer you use probably Microsoft SQL Server to hold the data. SQL Server supports very helpful type of data [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) (known as `timestamp` datatype too). A non-nullable `rowversion` column is semantically equivalent to a `binary(8)` column. The main advantage of the usage of `rowversion` is simplicity of the usage. SQL Server supports internal counter which associated with the database. The counter is accessible per `@@DBTS` variable. Every time when a row from a table of the database will be modified the `rowversion` column will be changed **automatically** to the value of `@@DBTS` and `@@DBTS` will be incremented. One can use additional `rowversion` column to easily determine whether any value in the row has changed since the last time it was read.

So if you have an existing database table you can just add one column which will hold rowversion (timestamp) of the row update counter. For example the statement

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users ADD RowUpdateTimeStamp rowversion NOT NULL
```

will add `RowUpdateTimeStamp` column of the type `rowversion` to the table `dbo.Users`. If you create new Users table you can do something like below

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Users (
    Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    FirstName nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(64) NOT NULL,
    RowUpdateTimeStamp rowversion NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Users PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC),
    CONSTRAINT UC_Users_LastName_FirstName UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (LastName ASC, FirstName ASC)
)
```

It creates the table which you described, but the table will have additional `RowUpdateTimeStamp` column of the type `rowversion`. It's important one more time to stress that one don't need to save any value in the column manually. SQL Server will automatically save/modify values of the column.

If you fill grid with the data from the table you can for example include hidden `RowVersion` column whit the value from `RowUpdateTimeStamp` column of the database table. The definition of the corresponding column in `colModel` looks like

```
name: "RowVersion", sortable: false, hidden: true, hidedlg: true,
editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }
```

It means that the value from hidden `RowVersion` will be send together with values of another editable columns.

The server methods which modify grid rows returns modified version of `RowUpdateTimeStamp`. I use `aftersavefunc` callback of [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) or `afterSubmit` of [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) to modifying `RowVersion` column of the grid with the value returned from the server.

If the server receives modification request from the client it has always `RowVersion` of the modifying row. The server code verifies whether the corresponding data in the database has less or equal value in 
`RowUpdateTimeStamp` column. It the database have higher value then *another* user already modified the data. In the case the server returns HTTP response with some error HTTP code (>=300). jqGrid interprets the response as an error and displays the corresponding error message. One can use [errorTextFormat](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#events) or [errorfunc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#editrow) to customize the error message.

I use the approach described above in all productive implementations. You can read additional information about the subject in [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663654/315935).

Comment: thank you very much. Just another small question below. I would be appreciated if you answer.

Comment: @Altan Alansu: If you have another question, post a new question or edit your existing one.