# Row Locking in jQGrid Edit

Tags: java, jdbc, jqgrid, edit, optimistic-locking

I want to implement row locking for jQGrid edits. Since my back end uses JDBC, I am thinking of using optimistic locking on the back end and if the lock is not obtained, then displaying an error message on the grid.

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better alternative? Is it possible to lock the row on the grid itself such that no other user (on a different system and browser) can edit a particular row while it is being edited ?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not JDBC developer. There are some common principals how one can implement concurrency control. One from the ways is [optimistic concurrency control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control). There are many implementation examples of such concurrency.

Because I work mostly with Microsoft SQL Server I use always the way with binary timestamp value saved in every row of tables of the database. I add in every table a column of non-nulable [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) type which is semantically equivalent to a `binary(8)` type. The main advantage is that **one don't need fill the column manually**. SQL Server hold a counter associated with the database. On every row insert or row update in any database table the column having `rowversion` will be assigned to the current value of the counter. After that the counter will be incremented. In the way one have "timestemp" of the row. If some modification take place with the row then one have increased value in the column having `rowversion` type. So to implement optimistic concurrency one need just extend every jqGrid table with additional hidden column which hold the `rowversion` value. If one need to modify the data I send the value of the hidden `rowversion` column to the server together with modified data. The request for modification should be interpreted in the following way: I get the data with the `rowversion` value and modified it to new value. My server code need to validate *before making the changes* whether the content of the data in the database still corresponds to the same `rowversion` value. If it's so then the data are not changed by other user and one can safe do the modification. If the value of `rowversion` is now higher then the server should return back to jqGrid error message about concurrency error. It's recommended to reload the grid with *current* data.

For more information about the implementation you can read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15326962/315935) and [this old one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2663654/315935).

I am not sure that you can use the describe above approach directly, because you use JDBC, but I think that the main idea of the implementation could be the same.

Comment: thanks a lot oleg ! but if i understand correctly, this will work in the following way: user 1 starts editing a row. At the same time, user 2 starts updating the same row, but when user 2 hits submit then an error message will be displayed. What if want the error message displayed before user 2 starts making any changes ? I want the warning to be shown as soon as the user clicks the edit button in the navigation bar.

Comment: @user2334092: No it works the following way: *a) user 1 **load the data** in grid. The data in grid stay in web browser. b) Later the user 2 loads and changes the data on his computer. c) the user 1 start changes the data in his web browser and try to save the changes.* I know that users hold many tabs in web browsers opened (I do this too). So I can see relatively old data in the tabs. If I start editing of the data I don't always reload the data before starting of editing. So the described situation is really important and can be very easy be reproduced.

Comment: but how will user 2 know that someone else is currently making changes ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean?

Comment: is there a way for the grid to throw an alert or error message by checking the version of the row as soon as a user click the edit button ?

Comment: I would like the grid to check the row for any changes in the version as soon as the edit button is clicked. if the version is changed then an error message can be displayed. otherwise the user can proceed with updating the row

Comment: I think I understand you now. You think really in some kind of *locking* of data on the backend. It's very bad in web scenario. Clients **don't hold typically no permanent connection to the server**. The client make HTTP GET request, fills the page and no other connections exist to the server. No lock of any data is required. The server can communicate with many thousand or even millions of clients. Only when some changing request will be send to the server the server can validate whether the client try to make changes *based on actual data* or the data are already changed in DB.

Comment: It's what one means under *optimistic concurrency*. What you ask will be real locking at the beginning of changes from one client (user 1). At the time *no users* are able to modify the same dataset. Such locking can follows to locking without unlocking. So it can be implemented only is *permanent* connection (with respect connection oriented protocol) exist between the client and the server. Only in the case the server are able to detect breaking of connections and unlocking of the row. Such scenario are not used in web development.

Comment: so you mean i'll have to involve code for maintaining and monitoring http sessions !

Comment: @user2334092: If you want you can implement some kind of data validation. You can send request to the server to validate `rowversion` **at starting of editing**. You can make asynchronous Ajax request inside of `beforeShowForm` in case of form editing and inside of `oneditfunc` in case of inline editing. In the way you can catch 99% of concurrency errors **before** the user start typing of new data. In any way you will have to continue implement the end control at saving of data. (to do what I described before)

Comment: @user2334092: No, I meant before that one should **never implement** any locking of data in case of web scenario.

Comment: why is that harmful ?

Comment: so this is what i am supposed to do: lets say i open up my grid and i start editing a row. then another user opens the same webpage on his machine. he is obviously unaware that i am making any changes. now the new user should see the row that i am working on, but he should not be allowed to make any changes to that row. in other words, the new user will see the row as disabled for the time i am making the changes.

Comment: @user2334092: If the web browser of the first user, the internet connection and so on will be broken then **the row will stay forever  locked**. You have to implement some custom cleanup routines which fill find and fix such situations. So one prefer another way which I described before: no locking, just optimistic concurrency control.